# How to get the current item of a List using AJAX?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Maybe the title is not so clear.

Imagine that I have two columns in the razor view.

One of the columns, show the following list.

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < questions.Length; i++) {
        <tr>
            <td><span>@i</span>.</td>
            <td class="questionText">@Html.ActionLink(questions[i].QuestionText, "AddItemToAssignmentContent", new { itemId = "Q" + questions[i].Id })
        </tr>
    }
```

As you can see, each one has a url.

Then, the second column is called `SelectedItems`, the purpuse of this is when you clic in a link of the first column, add the item to the second column.

I would like to do this using Ajax, but until now I don't know how to implemented with it.

Here is the action.

```
    public ActionResult AddItemToAssignmentContent(string itemId)
    {
        var list = Session["SelectedItems"] as List<CreateAssignmentSelectedItem>;

        CreateAssignmentSelectedItem item = new CreateAssignmentSelectedItem();
        item.Id = itemId;
        item.Display = itemId;
        item.Quantity = 5;

        list.Add(item);

        return PartialView("_SelectedAssignmentContent", list);
    }
```

What am I missing, or what am I supposed to do to add items to second column using AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by defining a javascript function which would get called on the execution of the click event of the link. The function will send the request async via ajax to the controller action, get the results (partial view) and populate the div

Mocked up function

```
function addQuestionToList(questionId){
    var linkToControllerAction = ‘@Url.Content(….)’

    $.ajax({
        url: linkToControllerAction,
        type: ‘post’,
        data: { ‘itemId’: questionId }
    }).done(function(partialViewResult){
         $(‘#divHostingThePartialView’).html(partialViewResult);
    });
}
```

And hook this function to the click event of each tr, that rendres the name of the question, replacing your action link